# Check if a package exists in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5, package, laravel-blade

I have a package in my Laravel project which simply displays text from the package blade view. All I do is publish the package view to my project's main view so that I could include the package view's text in my main view by the use of @include() method. How can I add a condition to check whether the package exists or is included in my project before I call its view?

Comment: In order words, how can I check whether the service provider for the package exists, since that is the one thing that gets checked for if the package is removed from my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `exists()` as:

```
if (view()->exists("package.view_name")) {
    // do some cool stuffs
}
```